# Laravel relationship within relationship to another table

Tags: laravel

I have users table, user_roles table and roles table.

My user_roles table:

```
id, role_id, user_id
```

My roles table:

```
id, name, description, created_at, updated_at
```

My users table:

```
id, first_name, last_name, user_name, avatar, account_status, email, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

Now I am trying to get the logged in user with the role including the role description, but cannot seem to get it working.

In my user model I have this:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User_roles::class, 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

This gives me the User_role but no description. I tried `belongsToMany`, but this gave me the `Roles` values and pivot with the `User_roles` table valus. Can I do it vice versa so I get the `User_roles` table values and pivot will be the description of the `Roles table`?

BelongsToMany relationship at the moment:

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class, 'user_roles', 'id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasManyThrough` relation instead:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

This way you can specify the intermediate `user_role` table

Answer (score 1):

You should try to below solution

**In User Model**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_roles');
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$roles = $user->roles;
```

Answer (score 0):

In User Model

```
public function roles()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```